# C# Process StandardOutput.ReadLine returns the wanted output, but this is erased with no reason

Tags: c#, process, mono, gtk, gtk#

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName="id";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments="-un";
proc.Start();
string nome_user = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Hi, I was trying to run a shell command using Mono GTK#. When the debugger is on the **proc.Start();** line, **proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()** added to watch shows the output correctly, but when the debugger jumps to the next line (**string nome_user = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();**), with no reason the value of the **proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()** turns into null. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you read it in the debugger, it's already been consumed from the stream. The stream won't magically rewind so it can be read again.

Comment: Now everything makes sense to me. Thank you, sorry for the stupidity.